# Help with identifying this "Cinelli" bike frame

Tags: road-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

Found this being sold for cheap locally, and I was wondering what type of frame this is, or if it is even a legit cinelli frame:

Tried googling it, but I can't find any leads. Thanks for the help!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
<sup>Photos from https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9k0i.jpg</sup>

Comment: Did you ask the seller? People who own bikes in this price class usually know what they have.

Comment: I asked him about it, and he said that it was a gift, and that it was a Cinelli Estrada. I asked for the year and other details, but he wasn't sure.

I tried googling for the Estrada, and it didn't look anything like that lol

Comment: Sounds a lot like "maybe fake, most likely stolen" to me. Faking the Cinelli logo stamped to frame would take some effort, though. The clumsy welds and shifter posts on down tube look like it's probably from early 2000s, someone with lots of time and image search can probably find what it is.

Comment: Yeah, I initially thought it was a fake, but the welded Cinelli logo seems like a lot of effort.

Comment: Mash - the logo on the seat stay - is a design shop that seems to have collaborated with Cinelli in the past. They sell mainly soft goods themselves. So, I wouldn’t rule this out as a real Cinelli bike yet.

Comment: A 'gift' is quite often another way to say that it was 'found' after the lock had  mysteriously fallen apart.

Comment: That weld is awful. Interesting how the Cinelli logo is on a part that of all parts would be the easiest to stamp and add later (to some random cheap Ali frame). Stamp flat, curve, weld on, repaint, apply decal, done.

Answer (score 3):

Start by contacting Cinelli with your frame's serial number, and whatever details you've got, like country of origin.

UK: https://www.cinellibicycles.co.uk/contact/ 
Italy: https://cinelli.it/en/contact-us/  
US: https://www.cinelli-usa.com/contact-us/

I would suspect its a `90s bike based on the fat frame tubes, back when Aluminium frames were overbuilt to account for the material properties of AL.

It may have had downtube shifters, but those bosses were also a normal fixture for integrated brifters.

---

The Maxzone headset is out of place - that brand seems to have origins in the Philippines.  Decidedly a long way from Italy.  I suspect this is more of a local replacement rather than an original part.

We can't see details of the outboard BB, but presume its been replaced too.

The frame clearly has a derailleur hanger, possibly non-replaceable, but can't really tell.  Whereas googling "cinelli mash" returns a lot of single speed and fixed gear stuff from the 2010-2020 period.  So I presume that MASH  was something and has been "pivoted" to single-speeds because of trends.
 Or its a sticker/decal that someone has slapped on the frame.

---

The only thing that puts me off the frame is that horrendous weld around the headstrap reinforcement.  It looks like painted bubblegum, and while I have no welding skills, that looks janky.

If you give it a good inspection all over, and see no damage then its probably okay to ride.  As long as the frame's a good size for you and not damaged, and seems like quality then whether its "real cinelli" or "Chinelly" doesn't matter that much.

Ultimately, you need to guess the cost of all the other parts you'll need, and the cost of the frame/fork, and see how that total compares to buying a complete bike, either new or used.  And availability comes into it too, this post-C19 world has some messed up supply lines.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the seller made it clear that the headset and the bottom bracket aren't original parts.

I was looking to buy it since it's being sold for less than $200, but the more I look at it, the more it feels like an imitation Cinelli.

I guess I'd just put my money towards buying a better bike instead of risking it with this weird frame.

Answer (score 2):

The decals say that the bike is a Cinelli MASH. Based on the documentation in the Cinelli catalogs this is not a Cinelli MASH. All MASH bikes were track bikes - this one is not.

The earliest [MASH Cinelli I can find is from 2010](https://issuu.com/bcoffey/docs/cinelli_2010). There is [no MASH in the 2009 catalog](http://labibleduvelocataloguescinelli.blogspot.com/p/cinelli-2009.html).

[image]

It's a track bike that was inspired by a movie that appears to have been made in 2007 about ["the fixed gear bike scene in and around San Francisco"](https://hypebeast.com/2007/5/mash-film-gabe-morford-mike-martin).

According to [this timeline the MASH model was introduced in 2009](https://cinelli.it/en/timeline-2/).

In the [2017 catalog there is a MASH](https://issuu.com/chickencyclekit/docs/cinelli-catalogue_2017lowres), in [2018 there is not](https://issuu.com/waterfall.pl/docs/cinelli_202018_20workbook).

I can find no Cinelli MASH models with frames that look like the one in the original post. The MASH model was a single speed track frame.
The current evidence leads me to believe that the decals are not original.

I can't find a bicycle in a catalog anywhere that has a frame like the one in the original post. There is a large gap in the catalog record between 1988 to 1992 and another large gap between 1992 and 2009. In 1992 Cinelli has all steel lugged bicycles so the area to focus on would be '92 to '09.

Comment: Good catch. However, the frame in the post has vertical dropouts and derailleur braze ons. It seems incongruous with something a fixed gear crowd would design.

Comment: This is not a track bike - I can just make out the rear dropouts in the last photo.   Also there's a cable holder for the rear derailleur wire visible on the right hand chainstay.

Comment: @Criggie - you are right the OP is not a track bike. Based on the documentation anything Cinelli made with MASH decals was a track bike. Whatever the OP is the decals are wrong.

Comment: @DavidD yep - I bet the decals are on top of the clear coat.   If it were me, I'd remove the fake decals and make my own, or maybe cut a small white "h" and put it inside the C of the logo, making a "CHINELLI"

Answer (score 2):

You have been given a number of answers suggesting the frame is not genuine Cinellli, perhaps because the welding is so obvious or because the decals are not correct.

I think it is obvious that the decals are incorrect, it looks to me like the frame has been repainted and a cheap set of Cinelli Mash decals have been fitted over the new paint.

Most of the earlier Cinelli frames -- and maybe the current ones too -- use Italian bottom bracket threading and if yours is Italian thread, it's a good clue it's a genuine Cinelli frame. The fact you have a stamped plate with the Cinelli logo suggests it is probably the genuine article too.

If you look back over the Cinelli catalogues, you can see this syle of aluminium welding is quite common at different times and was considered perfectly acceptable -- even desirable! -- at certain times in cycling history. All the Cinelli bikes cannot really be considered "mass market" as the volume of production was much smaller than many rivals. Image search may give you only one or two examples of each type of frame from a given year - if that - so not being able to find a match doesn't tell you anything. It's worth asking the distributor for your region if they recognise the welded C plate on your bike and can suggest the model, not that it really matters. It should be light and built up, it will ride like any quality mid range early 2000s aluminium frame; if that's your thing, it'll be great.

The paint looks nice. A beter decal kit would improve the look of the bike slightly. If you build it up and like it, that's probably the most important test.

It's a shame there are no Cinelli catalogues for such a big time period, it makes it hard to identify so many models.

Answer (score 2):

Its a Cinelli Pro Estrada aluminum: rare frame.
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  That does look similar; what year is it?  You could improve your answer by replicating the pictures in the question to make comparison easier.

Comment: Good find, well done.

Comment: @DavidW it's very unlikely anyone using Bissycals will be able to date

Comment: @Noise 1) "Bissycals"? 2) It's not _exactly_ the same; the fork especially is different, and probably more modern.  (Hence why dating it might help.)

Comment: @DavidW alrite dave, the ad he's copied in says 2015, which I consider very unlikely. At the very least it answers the OG question that the frame is legit.

Comment: "Bissycals" might be a typo for Bicycle ?  Google doesn't even know it as a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same frame but the paint has been removed, however the Cinelli logo is still molded into my frame. I've been using my bike since 2011 when I bought it on my neighbor, I still don't know what Cinelli frame/model this is. Hope some can help.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! This site is a little different from a typical forum. The expectation here is that users give a detailed yet direct and factual answer focused on the original question. "Answers" like this that basically just say "me too" are frowned upon. Instead, we upvote useful questions and answers. Please [Take the Tour](tour) for more information about how this and other Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: Why does everyone remove stickers and paint before trying to identify their bikes?

Comment: @ojs That might be a question worth posting :)